# Power Query Not Showing second decimal if zero

Tags: power-query

I'm having an issue in excels power query.

I can not figure out how to always show two decimal places.

For example, in excel it displays like this which is perfect

- 1.21 = 1.21
- 1.30 = 1.30

In Power Query It displays like this

- 1.21 = 1.21
- 1.30 = 1.3

Power Query removes the second decimal if its a zero. I'm trying to use this as a lookup by converting it to text as its my only unique number

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with adding a new column in the Power Query, you can use the Number.ToText function to convert it to Text with 2 decimal number.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous step", "Custom", each Number.ToText([Column1],"F"))
```